# Is it possible to launch a launch file from python?

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Final update:
The solution so far is modified from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage) with help from ufr3c_tjc. (Thank you loudly in my heart) So the original codes  from the link above is erroneous and won't work. The main part is remained:

```
class open_launch_file(): 
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('tester', anonymous=True)
        rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdown)

        uuid = roslaunch.rlutil.get_or_generate_uuid(None, False)
        roslaunch.configure_logging(uuid)
        launch = roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent(uuid,["/path/to/your/launch/file"])
        launch.start()

    def shutdown(self):
        rospy.loginfo("Stopping the robot...")
        destroy() #my own cleaning stuff function, you dont have to have it. but if there is anything you need to do before close the ros node, do it here.
        rospy.sleep(1)
```

===============================================================================

I have a .launch file that basically just open  the webcam. And I would like to call it from my python code when needed.
I searched online and found something like this: I have test other normal commands like "ls -l", "echo Hello world". And they are working fine. However, it would not work with the launch file

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["roslaunch ~/path/to/cam.launch "],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr = subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
print p.communicate()
```

the error message is:

```
'/bin/sh: 1: roslaunch: not found\n
```

I am using python 2.7

update:

the output of `printenv | grep PY` is:

```
INSIDE_CAJA_PYTHON=
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

When using the API example provide by ROS, there were errors that confuse me. I have set the environment correctly I believe.
When I `rosrun tester_pkg tester.py` , it gives error `NameError: name 'rospy' is not defined`

So I tried `sudo python tester.py` directly, it gives `ImportError: No module named roslaunch`

Thank you all for the replying. I am new to ROS and really need some helps.

update codes: tester.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslaunch
import rospy

rospy.init_node('tester', anonymous=True)
rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdown)

uuid = roslaunch.rlutil.get_or_generate_uuid(None, False)
roslaunch.configure_logging(uuid)
launch = roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent(uuid,["/home/yue/catkin_ws/src/webcam_car/launch/cam.launch"])

launch.start()

launch.shutdown()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263862/if-it-possible-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python?/) by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-14**:
Don't use sudo. That will run it as root, which will never work unless ROS is installed as root. `line 3: syntax error near unexpected token` is telling you the issue. Look at line 3 of the file and see what could be wrong (or post the file for us to see).

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-14**:
NameError: name 'rospy' is not defined

Add `import rospy`

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-14**:
Thank you!
But now the error become

```
rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdown)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-14**:
the line 3 error is fixed by adding `#!/usr/bin/env python`. stupid missing.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-14**:
Can you edit the question with the file's code you are trying to run? That will make it much easier to help you.

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-14**:
sure. It's basically the sample II from the roslaunch API page.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-14**:
The `self.shutdown` part is weird. The `self` keyword is only used in a class context. Just remove that line completely. Also, this script will immediately start then shutdown the launch file, so maybe just remove the `launch.shutdown()` part until you decide how/when you want to shut it down.

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-14**:
I found comment about the self.shutdown # Set rospy to exectute a shutdown function when terminating the script
Remove this line and the launch.shutdown() works as I can see the process being created! But still the launch file shutdown itself.
I guess I can take over from here now! Thank you so muc

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-14**:
thank you for you patient! :)

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-14**:
Yes, the `rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdown)` will run the shutdown function if your have one defined, when running inside a class. It's just weird that their example doesn't have a class, so it errors. Remove the `launch.shutdown()`, this is what's causing it to stop.

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-15**:
It happened after I removed launch.shutdown statement. Actually the terminal looks the same with or without it. That's weird. I'm looking into the documents.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-15**:
It because the script ends. Put in a `rospy.spin()` line at the end, and it will wait and not exit until told to do so by the ros master.

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-16**:
Turns out the `rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdown)` is quiet important. otherwise, the node wont stop by ctrl -c any more. So I modify the code into one with class. The attribute 'shutdown' also must be writen. I would update my detailed solution so far for future newbies like me.

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-16**:
thank you for your kindness help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-17**:
Please post your final update as an answer and then accept your own answer. That way there is a clear answer to this question, and it's also visible from the main question listing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please use the search first in the future, this has been asked multiple times already. That sounds harsh, and we do want to help you, but with almost 35000 questions on this site it gets increasingly important to avoid duplicates.

As to your question: yes, this is possible, you'll just have to make sure that the environment in which you run your Python script has already been setup with the appropriate environment variables. In other words: run it from a terminal in which you have `source`d the correct `setup.bash`, and make sure your `Popen` call inherits the environment from its caller.

As an alternative: do not start `roslaunch ..` directly in your `Popen` call, but use a small wrapper script that first `source`s the `setup.bash` and then executes `roslaunch`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct way to do this is to use the actual roslaunch Python API. Do not use calls to `subprocess` etc. It gets way too messy to control environment variables and makes stopping the processes much harder. Using the proper API allows you to start, but also to stop, the launch file nodes easily. See [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage) for examples.

Again though, that API page is the second Google result for 'roslaunch python'. Please do some searching before posting next time :)

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-14**:
actually this was the first thing I tried. It gave error of cannot find module roslaunch.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-14**:
Then your path must be set up incorrectly. Can you edit the question to show the output of `printenv | grep PY`. It should include something like `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-14**:
Also make sure that you're running the python script from a shell that has the correct environment variables set (ROS_PACKAGE_PATH etc.), otherwise it won't work.

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-14**:
the output is:

```
    INSIDE_CAJA_PYTHON=
    PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-14**:
That part is at least correct, but it doesn't have your own workspace in the path. I assume that you always `source devel/setup.bash` before running your code from within your own workspace? Also, what is the output of `printenv | grep ROS`?

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-14**:
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/yue/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/yue/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-15**:
@ufr3c_tjc: using the `roslaunch` Python API is indeed a better approach, but I did not want to complicate things too much for @yue.z, seeing as he already states that he is a beginner.

**Comment by [yue.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/30764/yue.z/) on 2017-06-15**:
"she". I will try both ways to see which one fit my need if I could make them work.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-06-19**:
The first search result for 'roslaunch python' for me is about launching python nodes from roslaunch, and about half the following results are also for that opposite case.  Also, using the proper api is very messy if you want to do something like pass in parameters, unless using lunar or later.